# ionic 4: Trying to display portion of Timestamp field but getting an error

Tags: firebase, timestamp, ionic4

I'm trying to display a timestamp on my ionic 4 html page but I am getting an error - here is the code within the html

```
<ion-title> {{currentDetails?.date.seconds | date: 'dd-MM-yyy'}} </ion-title>
```

and here is the error I am getting

```
DetailsPage.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (DetailsPage.html:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22503)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21878)
    at callViewAction (co....
```

I have used similar code to display the date in other areas of the code and it seems to be error free.

Comment: If date can be undefined why not try a safe navigation operator there? `currentDetails?.date?.seconds` ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough detail in there but I'll assume that `currentDetails?.date` is a javascript date object. If yes, then you can use the extension method `getTime()` to get the timestamp in milliseconds

```
{{currentDetails?.date.getTime() | date: 'dd-MM-yyy'}}
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize that. Safe navigation should do it then.